# Laravel 5 works fine in local but not work in live server

Tags: laravel-5

Recently i have make an app with laravel 5. My app is working fine in locally but in live server it always token mismatched. Session is not working. I have changed the Storage directory's permission 777,also tried with new app with existing controller,view,model and other but it still work fine in local not in server.I am really passing painful day,please anybody help me.

Comment: Share your apache configuration info.

Comment: There are a lot of settings by phpinfo(),please mention which are you looking for.

Comment: Did you recursively change the permissions of the `storage` directory? Are you getting a token mismatch error for all requests? (because the token is checked only on non-read requests)

Comment: For every post request i got token mismatch. My app root path restricted for auth. When i hit root path it shows on screen redirecting to mydomain.com/auth/login. When i try to login it shows token mismatch. Actually everything are fine in my local server. @bogdan

Comment: Have you changed your apache root directory with DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_dir/public/ ?